# How to recover root nodes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tree, nested

Using symfony2 and doctrine2 with doctrine tree extension, I have recently updated an entity to make it a doctrine nested set tree.

A doctrine schema update force added the right columns with null data.

Then I ran the following code :

```
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Recipe');

        $repo->verify();
// can return TRUE if tree is valid, or array of errors found on tree
        $repo->recover();
        $this->flush(); // important: flush recovered nodes
// if tree has errors it will try to fix all tree
```

It successfully recovered left right and level values but not root.
I can't manually set root values (prohibited by doctrine listener).

How can I update those root values so the tree could work properly ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple root nodes and multiple sub categories you can run this query :

```
UPDATE category SET category.tree_root = IF(category.parent_id IS NULL, category.id, category.parent_id)
```

It will set the category id as the tree node only if it has no parent (so its a root category) otherwise it will set the parent id as the tree id.

then fix, running :

```
$em->clear();
$repository->verify();
$repository->recover();
$em->flush();
```

Example of data set:

- restaurant (id: 1, tree root: 1)

  - pizza (id: 2, tree root: 1)
  - burger (id: 3, tree root: 1)
- bar (id: 4, tree root, 4)

  - coktail bar (id: 5, tree root: 4)
  - dj bar (id: 6, tree root: 4)
- shop (id: 7, tree root: 7)

  - bakery (id: 8, tree root: 7)
  - ice cream (id: 9, tree root: 7)
  - wine shop (id: 10, tree root: 7)

Answer (score -1):

Well, i did not find an object oriented solution so I went for a raw SQL query.
i'm doing this before any entity gets a parent, therefore each entity's root value should equal its own id.

In phpmyadmin, paste the following sql query and execute :

```
update recipe
set recipe.root = recipe.id
```